# Why is PHP 8.1.1 not loading PDO driver using Apache 2.4.52 even the modules are loaded on PHP CLI?

Tags: php, apache2, php-8.1

Why is PHP 8.1.1 not loading PDO driver using Apache 2.4.52 even the modules are loaded on PHP CLI?

I am running a window 11 64bit system
I tried Apache/2.4.52 (Win64) (Apache 2.4 VS16) and Apache 2.4.x OpenSSL 1.1.1 VC15 from https://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx#MODULES24VS16.

I installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2019 Redistributable (VS16) from above site too.
I installed PHP 8-1.1 VS16 x64 Thread Safe (2021-Dec-15 11:08:34) from https://windows.php.net/download#php-8.1.

I enabled the extensions (uncommented).

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlit
extension=pgsql

extension_dir = "c:\php-8.1.1\ext"
```

Now the issues:

In version Apache 2.4 VS16 Apache is not starting
httpd.exe -t
Cannot load c:\php-8.1.1\php8apache2_4.dll into server: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

configuration on httpd.conf:

```
PHPINIDir "c:/php-8.1.1/php.ini"
LoadModule php_module "c:\php-8.1.1\php8apache2_4.dll"
```

in Apache VC15 the server starts but the PDO driver is not loading in phpinfo()
PDO drivers no value
curl is not loaded
pgsql is not loaded

php cli is working.

```
c:\Apache24\bin>php -m
[PHP Modules]
...
curl
PDO
pdo_pgsql
pgsql
....
[Zend Modules]
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my problem by adding the PHP ext folder path in extension_dir on php.ini
I changed "" to "/" and it worked.

```
extension_dir = "c:/php-8.1.1/ext"
```

Comment: This way the PDO mysql and odbc drivers appear in phpinfo() but I can't make the PDO sqlite drive appear

Comment: Make sure the  ";" is removed from (;extension=pdo_sqlite) extension in php.ini.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, on the same operating system. Solved it when I changed Apache 2.4.52 VC16 to VC15. PHP loaded the extensions normally

Comment: Please post answers in English.